# What should be used for Android app: Parse SDK or Parse RestAPI?

Tags: android, parse-platform

My application has some complicated database operations, Almost all the sql queries i have to use.

If I want server based access to my data, what should i choose to communicate with Parse server: SDK is good, but I know there is an API as well.

I think SDK will not provide a lot of accesses, operations like email verification, complex db operation can't be handle through it. and I don't know anything of server side coding.

Please suggest , Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to first read these

[All the limits of parse](http://profi.co/all-the-limits-of-parse/)

[Parse SDK review](http://profi.co/parse-sdk-review/)

The second one is for iOS, but it's basically the same for Android. (I basically copied Objective-C code to Java, especialy the requests)

If you are sure you want to make complex app on Parse, then I would probably suggest to go for SDK. It is not that restricting, but will probably be hard to understand in the beggining, but you can do whatever you want if you setup good arhitecture from the start. :)
(But. It's only my opinion)